# How can I find a python module absolute path and import it?

Tags: python, import, path

I wrote a module and placed it in a directory in my project, for example:

```
projectRoot/src/lib/myModule.py
```

I have many different applications in my project that are using this module but each resides in a different library and is being executed from a different location, so for example one application might need to insert this module before import in the following way:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '../../src/lib/myModule.py')
```

while another will use:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '../lib/myModule.py')
```

On the other hand I can just place the absolute path as such:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'home/user/projectRoot/src/lib/myModule.py')
```

How do I go about this? I tried the following method but I think I didn't get it right as it game me my project root with the module - projectRoot/myModule.py - which is not correct.

```
path('myModule.py').abspath()
```

Bottom line is that I dont know who will need this module and from were it will be executed (python module in Jenkins will also use it) and need to get the correct path before importing the module.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking `sys.path` is likely to lead into confusion, misery and other things, especially when you start thinking about how your addon modules would import other modules of their own.

Instead of trying to manipulate `sys.path`, your addon modules should be made installable and importable as regular Python packages (see https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/); then you can just import them by name with `importlib.import_module()` (or use entrypoints to enumerate all of them!).